# revenuecat - how originalAppUserId does it work?

Tags: android, flutter, subscription, revenuecat

I am using a Auto-renewable subscriptions in my app(Android/Flutter). Now I using “test card”/test mode. This is my user case:

1. My test user have google acc test@test.com(example).
2. I create a subscription for the first time. I got originalAppUserId - value1.
3. time passes 20-30 (minutes) - the test subscription becomes inactive. also i can uninstall the app.
4. I create a new subscription (second time). I got originalAppUserId - value2.
5. the value1 of originalAppUserId  the first and second times are not equal.
   this is right? I expected that these values will be equal(Unique and equal value for current google acc).

Can I get unique value from store account(email/id) using  sdk? or is it imposiible?

then I need to create the user id myself? For example, add authorization to the application using a Google account? will this work?

any options - I will be very grateful for the help.